# Error while making a connection in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I get the following message whenever I run the code

> throw new Error('Most middleware (like ' + name + ') is no longer
>   bundled with express and must be installed separately  ^ Error: Most
>   middleware(like BodyParser) is no longer bundled with Express and must
>   be installed separately.

My code is as following:

```
var express = require("express"),
restful = require("node-restful");
mongoose = restful.mongoose;

var app = express();
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/restful")

var ProductSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    sku:String,
    price:Number
});
var Products = restful.model("products", ProductSchema);
Products.methods(["get", "put", "post", "delete"]);
Products.register(app, "/api/products");

app.listen(3000);
Console.log("Server is running at port 3000")
```

I've installed [npm body parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) and [npm method override](https://www.npmjs.com/package/method-override) separately but it still gives me the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you do not require body-parser.

You should have something like `var bodyParser = require('body-parser');` and then use it like `app.use(bodyParser.json());`if you want the json parser for example.

Since it is no longer in express, you cannot require it and use it through express